# How to run a query when the page is finished loading?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
// last_seen
+----+---------+--------------+
| id | id_user |     time     |
+----+---------+--------------+
| 1  | 545     | 1339412843   |
| 2  | 653     | 1339422601   |
| 3  | 813     | 1339412612   |
| 4  | 1030    | 1339717631   |
+----+---------+--------------+
```

Every user has a row in table above. That row contains a *unix_time* which declares the time of last seen for each user.

Also I have this PHP script *(named `update_last_seen.php`)* which updates last seen for each user per every request:

```
// user is logged
if( isset($_SESSION["LoginValidation"]) && $_SESSION["LoginValidation"] == 1 ) {

   // it is ajax request
   if( !empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) &&
       strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) === "xmlhttprequest" ) {

        $db
        ->prepare("UPDATE last_seen SET time = ? WHERE id_user = ?")
        ->execute(array(time(), $_SESSION['id']));

   } -- ajax
} -- logged
```

Currently I run script above first of all into `index.php`. I mean each page updates `last_seen` table before loading. So the request does get slowed down by the update.

Now I'd make that an AJAX push request when the page finished loading. Is there any JS event to detect page is loaded completely?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use the vanilla JS event DOMContentLoaded and make an ajax call to the file.
Put ajax functionality in the

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //put your code here
});
```

Comment: the code run after pageload if you put code in this block..

Comment: @Stack you are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the vanilla JS event [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) and make an ajax call to the file.

Or you could use jQuery [`.ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) and [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/last_seen.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { id: '3' }
    }).done(function(data){

    });

});
```

Comment: @Stack you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know in vanilla JS you just have to call DOMContentLoaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   //insert code here
});
```